# Access host cmd from guest

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Slackware as a guest on Win 7 Virtualbox as host. On the Slack i'm running ssh server which i can access from outside (by port forwarding). Is there a way to issue a commands on host (for e.g. start host's ssh server) via ssh server on guest?

Answer (score 1):

No.

If there is no SSH Server running on your windows machine (the host), there is no way to use ssh from the guest OS...